# Incomplete sentences in a resume

Tags: resume

I have read how the use of the word I isn't always necessary when writing a resume as the employer already knows that the resume belongs to the job applicant. However some of these sentences sound incomplete without the word I, So i would like to know if its really necessary to include the word I in the beginning of these sentences.

1.I have maintained a clean record, both at school and work,......

2.I grew up in a respectable household and was brought up to appreciate and uphold moral values.

3.I strictly adhere to instructions and devote ......

OR

1.Maintained a clean record, both at school and work.....

2.Grew up in a respectable household and was brought up to appreciate and uphold moral values.

3.Strictly adhere to instructions and devote .........

Note: I am not asking anyone to proofread my sentences , I just want to know if i can use the sentences with or without I in the beginning.

Comment: I will point out that even without the "I" those particular sentences are things I would not want to see in a resume.

Comment: Also, 1 and 2 have no place on a resume. If you must, put them in a cover letter. But someone who thinks a clean record is significant (rather than just being a given) is a little off-putting, and people who tell me right off the bat they have strong morals will usually inspire me to tuck a plate under the back of my shirt.

Comment: Curious to know what job are you applying for?

Answer (score 10):

> I just want to know if i can use the sentences with or without I in
>   the beginning.

Yes, you can (and I believe should) use sentences without "I".

In general, we know your resume is about you - there's no confusion. Your resume will look awkward littered with the word "I" in practically every sentence.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/five-tips-for-better-resume-writing.html

Answer (score 5):

Your resume (CV) is an "impactful" document, and so it should use impact statements. Whenever addressing what you've done, how you did it, or how great it was, you should use the strongest verb possible and embellish only with light adjectives. Avoid the overuse of adverbs, and never begin a sentence with one. Your second example is the better of the 2 practices where "I" is assumed.

Consider that most people reading this document will already be acquainted with "who" in every stage of the game. In that context, when you include "I" in every other sentence it becomes very visually distracting. You'll also notice that the repetition will cause your resume to "river" with hard white lines between spaces. This is very visually distracting, and someone reading may unconsciously stop paying attention to what you're really saying if their eyes are too busy trying to adjust to the shape of the words on the page.